# SQL Server Concatenate Join

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, join, left-join

I want to create a left join between a concatenate result of two columns of the main table and another column of the second table.
My question is, should this join affect the query performance?
Is there any better way to do it?

```
Table A: Column1, Column2
Table B: Column3
```

---

```
Select *
from Table A left Outer Join
     Table B on Column1+Column2=Column3
```

I appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server as per the title or MySQL as per the tags?

Comment: The title says SQL Server, but MySQL us tagged. Which of these products are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine,

For SQL Server

```
Select *
from `Table A` as a left Outer Join
     `Table B` as b on a.Column1 + a.Column2 = b.Column3
```

For MySQL use `concat()`

```
Select *
from `Table A` as a left Outer Join
     `Table B` as b on concat(a.Column1,a.Column2) = b.Column3
```

Comment: **(1)** If this is the condition then this is the condition. **(2)** No special issues what so ever. All Joins algorithm are valid here.